# convert multi object to array of multiple object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to convert that object into an array in javascript?

```
{
    "0": {
        "category": "Private",
        "price": "5"
    },
    "1": {
        "category": "VIP",
        "price": "5"
    },
    "2": {
        "category": "Premium",
        "price": "5"
    },
}
```

expected result :

```
pricing=[
  { category: "Private", price: 5 },
  { category: "VIP", price: 5 },
  { category: "Premium", price: 5 },
]
```

Comment: Your expected result is an invalid data structure. Did you just want an array of objects?

Comment: `Object.values(input)` will do the work.

Comment: sure not using Java - http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ Why the [tag:java] tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Easiest way would be using `Object.values` and then `.map()` into objects

```js
const array = Object.values(obj).map(item => ({ 
  property1: item.property1, 
  property2: item.property2 
}));
```

```js
const obj = {
    "0": {
        "category": "Private",
        "price": "5"
    },
    "1": {
        "category": "VIP",
        "price": "5"
    },
    "2": {
        "category": "Premium",
        "price": "5"
    },
};

const array = Object.values(obj).map(item => ({
  category: item.category,
  price: Number(item.price)
}));

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Re missing the radix from `parseInt`: [_"Be careful — this does not always default to 10!"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: May we use Number("") ??

Comment: Sure. It's more idiomatic imo.

Comment: I edited my answer, thanks for the contribution!